# Bootstrap grid offset not centering

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

Trying to center my sign up page, but my `class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4"` isn't working.
I know there's other means to centering the text, but I just want to know what I've done wrong in my code, so I can know to avoid it in the future.

My `HTML` is:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
   <div class="well">
            <h2>Sign up</h2>

    <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
      <%= devise_error_messages! %>

      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :email %><br />
        <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :password %>
        <% if @minimum_password_length %>
        <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
        <% end %><br />
        <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>
      </div>

      <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
      </div>
    <% end %>

    <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I've read other posts, and their answers are just that they forgot a container tag or something. Can't find any answer in the bootstrap documentation either. I'm assuming it's something small I'm overlooking.

Comment: what is the version of your bootstrap (3 or 4)

Comment: Your text isn't centered. But your column is. Works as it should..

Comment: @widjajayd v4.3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No idea what happened.
I removed the breaks between some of the code, and it worked.
I put the line breaks back, and it still worked. I have no idea. Maybe my browser was having problems? Literally no idea, but it's working now

Answer (score 2):

just change col-md-offset-4 to offset-md-4 since bootstrap 4 change this

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-4">
```

here is [reference for this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#offsetting-columns)

Comment: Appreciate the help, but that hasn't centered it either. I read that article, but didn't seem to help

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
```

Try this. That is what I use most times.

Answer (score 1):

You must change this part as bellow.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-4">
```

just change this part.